# Error al validar RFC de México con Laravel Livewire regex

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, livewire

Intento crear un Registro federal de contribuyente (RFC) de México con expresiones regulares en laravel y livewire pero me mada el siguiente error:

"preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found"

A continuacion mi codigo:

```
public function store(){
    $validatedDate = $this->validate([
        'nombre' => 'required',
        'rfc' => "required|regex:/^([A-Z]{3,4})(\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))([A-Z\d]{2}(?:[A\d]))?$/"
    ]);

    Supplier::create([
        'nombre' => $this->nombre,
        'rfc' => $this->rfc
    ]);           
}
```

Algo esta mal con la validacion del campo rfc, especificamente con el regex.  Ayuda!